# how to read how many objects created in python program and save as a list

Tags: python

I am creating 4 objects in python like below

```
ex:
a=10
b=30
c=b-a
```

In above program I am creating 3 objects(variables) because I able to see how many variables are there. If no.of variables are there how to read their count and how to keep in a list like see below examples

```
count=3

list1 =[a,b,c]
```

Comment: is it okay to use a `dict` ? Like `d={}` then `d['a'] = 10, d['b']=30, d['c'] = d['b'] - d['c']`. You can get the count by `len(d)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)  to get the list of variables created.

Example

```
a = 10
b = 30
c = b-a

# Capture the integer variables created
all_variables= globals()                # dictionary of all variables and functions
lst = [k for k, v in all_variables.items() if type(v) == int]  # list of integer variables
print(lst)           # Output: ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(len(lst))      # Output: 3

# Example of accessing values
for var in lst:
    print(f'variable {var} has value {globals()[var]}')
# Output:
variable a has value 10
variable b has value 30
variable c has value 20
```